# ganglia stops after rebooting the collector server

Tags: ganglia

I have 3 machines. One of them collects ganglia data for all 3 of them. When I reboot this "collector" server, both gmetad and ganglia-monitor are started from the /etc/rc3.d, and I can see in tcpdump that the other 2 servers send the monitoring data every 15 seconds, however only the "collector" server's data show up in the web GUI.

The only way I can get the other servers show up in the graphs again is: stop ganglia-monitor on the remote servers, wait 'till the servers show up as "offline", then start ganglia-monitor on the remote again.

I'm pretty sure this should work out of the box, any idea what can be wrong?

Comment: Which version are you running?

Comment: ganglia-monitor 3.1.7 (from ubuntu 12.04)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't sound like a configuration problem. What version of Ganglia are you using? My off-the-cuff suggestion would be to upgrade to a new version of Ganglia and if one is not available as a package then download the latest and compile it.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like:

> send_metadata_interval = 30 /*secs */

When only in unicast mode. See https://serverfault.com/a/422273/25640